# How to read error messages in C (runtime error 166 : 36)?

Tags: c, runtime-error, cs50

I have two questions: What does 36 mean in the error message, and what is the problem with these lines of code?

My programme compiles but when I run it I get a runtime error message. Obviously, it's trying to assign the value 256 to a bitmap colour channel which should be capped at 255. Here's the error message:

```
helpers.c:166:36: runtime error: 256 is outside the range of representable values of type 'unsigned char'
```

166 is the line where the problem is, but what does 36 means? I'm going hundreds of thousands of times through that loop, how can I debug this?
The other thing is that I don't understand why it won't register 255; Here's my code:

```
if (round(sqrt(xg * xg + yg * yg)) > 255)
{
    temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = 255;
}
else
{
    temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(sqrt(xg * xg + yg * yg));
}
```

Last line is 166.

I'll be thankful for any light.
Al.

Comment: 166:36, line 166, column 36 (36th character on the 166th line). this gives you a rough location of where the problem occurred on the line to help give you a hint.

Comment: avoid doing calculation twice. `unsigned char tmp=round(sqrt(xg * xg + yg * yg)` and replace it with tmp inside condition and else statement

Comment: What data types are xg and yg?

Comment: Thanks for the help. xg and yg are integers.

Comment: Nobody ever remembers [`hypot()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/hypot.3.html) exists.

Comment: No problem. It's hard to tell without looking at the rest of your code. I was hoping that the data types were characters or something more likely to overflow and cause this problem. I agree with Roim that doing the calculation once will help here, but if the result really is 256 then i can't understand how it can possibly go to the "else" (without looking at more of your code).

Comment: Thank you Roim This seems to have solve the run time problem.

Comment: Are there multiple threads running that could change the value xg/yg between the if comparison and assignment? Did you remove any other lines of code for simplicity or is this the full example?

Comment: No, there' s nothing between those lines that interferes. I followed Roim and Elliott 's advice. Doing the calculation only once solved the problem. Now the programme can run all the way through, and I can finally see the result. And it's not pretty! My logic is all wrong. This is week 4 of cs50 and I'm struggling.